# lateinit property presenter has not been initialized with EasyMVP, Robolectric and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, robolectric, android-mvp

I have problem while trying to use Robolectric to test activity which is using EasyMvp.
All of the classes are written in Kotlin.

This is beginning of an activity:

```
@ActivityView(layout = R.layout.activity_access, presenter = AccessPresenterImpl::class)
class AccessActivity : BaseActivity(), AccessView {

@Presenter
lateinit var presenter: AccessPresenter

override fun providePresenter(): BasePresenter? {
    return presenter
}
```

And at the onStart, every activity is initializing extras in presenter.

I was trying to introduce Robolectric tests in my app.

```
var activity: AccessActivity? = null
var loginEditText: EditText? = null
var passwordEditText: EditText? = null

@Before
fun initData() {
    activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(AccessActivity::class.java)
    loginEditText = activity?.findViewById(R.id.loginEditText)
    passwordEditText = activity?.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText)
}
```

But while Running the test, I am always getting error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property presenter has not been initialized
```

I assume that this is problem with Robolectric annotation proccessing. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Does the error  occur only in the test? Does it run fine without the test?

Comment: Yes, only in the test. I am using EasyMVP everywhere in my app.

Comment: Did you tried this with a nullable presenter.

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it is impossible in EasyMVP.

Comment: Are you referring this project https://github.com/JorgeCastilloPrz/EasyMVP

Comment: It is definitely not annotation processing. Where in EasyMVP presenter is constructed?